# How coarsening rate affects MG convergence?

Tags: multigrid

If we use an aggresive coarsening how does this affect the convergence of a MG cycle?Is the convergence slower?Do we need more cycles in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quicker coarsening means that your coarse grid correction is not as good and that you need more MG cycles. For a well-tuned multigrid, you reduce the error by about a factor of 5-10 for each CG iteration with MG V-cycle preconditioner. If you were to coarsen too aggressively, the reduction factor would be smaller.

Comment: And the reason for this is that with a more aggressive coarsening we lose information about some nodes?(assume canonical restriction)

Comment: Correct. The solution on the more-coarser level is just not as good an approximation as the one on the less-coarser level.